# Extending requirejs config paths outside of main.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requirejs, with config paths set in main.js like so:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'async'     : 'modules/async',
        'jquery'    : 'modules/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        'moment'    : 'modules/moment'
    }
})
```

Within main.js, these paths work fine, and I can reference them like so:

```
require(['async','moment'], function(async,moment) {
    //
})
```

But within an html file I am serving that loads the requirejs script, when I try to do a require call like the code block above this, it no longer recognizes the path, and interprets `require(['jquery']` as the file `./jquery.js`, instead of the path I specified. How can I make sure that it instead maps to the config path I created?

Comment: Could you show your html file?